# How far away must I stand to not hear sound (interference)

Tags: waves, acoustics

I`ve been trying for a while. I have two speakers with 4 meters between them with music playing on 250 Hz so the wavelength is 1.36 meters, How far away do i have to stand in front of one of the speakers (horizontally) to not hear anything, how many meters, if From where I am standing makes the two speakers and me an right angeled triangle

Comment: Is your question about interference?

Comment: Calculate the distance with the condition that the lenght difference between the two path must be a multiple of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$. Keep in mind that you have to synchronize the phase of the two speakers if you want your experiment to work.

Answer (score 2):

You will get destructive interference when the difference in the distances from you to the two speakers is $n + \tfrac{1}{2}$ wavelengths. In your case that's 0.68m, 2.04m, 3.4m, and so on. You get constructive interference when the difference in the distances is an integral number of wavelengths.

However the experiment is hard to do in a living room because the sound echoes off the walls and the echoes blur out the interference pattern. Unless you take the speakers outside or use an anechoic chamber you'll struggle to hear much difference.